# Or operator in observe event

Tags: shiny

Is there a way to make sure either of the action buttons are pressed, the event should trigger. In the below example, the output is to be printed when either of the buttons pressed

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("act1", "Action1"),
  actionButton("act2", "Action2"),
  htmlOutput("gh")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  observeEvent((input$act1 | input$act2),{
    output$gh <- renderUI({
      "Clicked"
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `observeEvent` has other arguments such as `ignoreInit`, just set it to `TRUE`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("act1", "Action1"),
  actionButton("act2", "Action2"),
  htmlOutput("gh")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  observeEvent((input$act1 | input$act2),{
    output$gh <- renderUI({
      "Clicked"
    })
  },ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```